# Divide scatter plot into chunks and calculate means

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, mean, scatter-plot

I have three lists, each consists of 200 values:

```
list_y = [130.2423, 142.923, 150.234, 123.2523, 109.135, 98.34234, ...]
list_x_1 = [0.234, 0.5364, 0.5675, 0.1342, 0.8234, 0.61234, ...]
list_x_2 = [0.979, 0.3457, 0.2556, 0.7456, 0.3732, 0.96532, ...]
```

So far I have created two basic scatter plots (y, list_x_1) and (y, list_x_2) like this one: [image: example]

I tried to add vertical lines to the plots where the range of x is divided into 5 chunks and in each chunk, there are an equal amount of points. Within each chunk, I'd like to calculate the mean of y.

Any ideas on how to achieve and plot this?

EDIT:
If I divide both lists into 5 equal parts (each sublist has 40 values) like this:

```
list_y = [[list with the first 40 values], [next 40 values], [""], [""], [""]]
list_x_1 = [[list with the first 40 corresponding values], [next 40 values], [""], [""], [""]]
```

and I calculate the mean of each sublist, this is not the same as calculating the mean of the chunks based on the scatter-plot.

Comment: simply divide you data into 5 equals parts, then calculate mean for each part.

Comment: See my edit above